# How to get a handle on each uitableviewcontroller in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I have a tabbar application with each tab directing user to a UITableViewController.  I created another object called MyTimer that extends NSObject. I want MyTimer to execute the function `[MyTimer refreshTables]` every minute.  The contents of the refreshTables function will look somethign like this

```
-(void) refreshTables:(NSTimer *)timer
{
[tabbar.firstuitableviewcontroller.tableView reloadData];
[tabbar.seconduitableviewcontroller.tableView reloadData];
[tabbar.thirduitableviewcontroller.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The problem is that I don't know the correct syntax or chain of variable names I need to use to get a handle tabbar.firstuitableviewcontroller, tabbar.seconduitableviewcontoller etc...  Can i get a handle on them from the appdelegate object?  or some other way?

Thanks

Comment: It is wasteful to reload data on all tables inside a tab bar view, because only one of them is visible at a time. I think it is better to refresh only the currently visible one on timer, and also set a stale flag on the model, so that when a tab is changed to a table view with a stale table, you could trigger an immediate refresh right then.

Comment: sure i'll do that.  But do you know how I can programmatically access to the tableview of each tableviewcontroller from my MyTimer?  That would be a good basic for me to learn

Comment: Try the square brackets syntax: `[[[tabbar  firstuitableviewcontroller] tableView] reloadData]`

Comment: oh and how do i grab the tabbar?  is it a property of the appdelegate objecT?  thanks

Comment: Yes, it is often on the app delegate. In some sample apps it's called `_tabBar`.

Comment: I have a property not found error when calling appdelegate._tabBar or [appdelegate _tabBar]. Any ideaS?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11352/discussion-between-john-and-dasblinkenlight)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the rootviewcontroller of my appdelegate was teh tabbarcontroller.  So this was valid:

UITabBarController * uitbc = appDelegate.window.rootViewController;

THen i can grab the navigation controller each tab points to by :

// change zero to the index of another tab if you want another one instead
UINavigationController * uinc = [uitbc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];